# WPF/MVVM. Print multiple pictures in a single process

Tags: wpf, mvvm, printdialog

I have to print all pictures stored in a directory. Users' request is that the print preview dialog should be displayed so that they can choose the page arrangement ([see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKePM.png)).
I tried to use the Process tool, but it works only for one file. Here is the code:

```
Dim info As New ProcessStartInfo()
info.Verb = "print"

info.FileName = "C:\Pictures\pic1.jpg"
info.LoadUserProfile = True

Dim p As New Process()
Try
    p.StartInfo = info
    p.Start()
    p.WaitForExit()
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
    If False = p.CloseMainWindow() Then
        p.Kill()
    End If
Catch i As System.InvalidOperationException
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
End Try
```

This works. When I try to set info.FileName to "C:\Pictures\pic1.jpg C:\Pictures\pic2.jpg", or "[pic1];[pic2]", or "*.*"; but I always get the error message

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception {"could not find file"}

How can I configure it to select all files in the directory?

Comment: You can iterate the result from  `Directory.GetFiles` to print all files in a folder.

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
using System.IO;
:
:
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Pictures\", "*.jpg");
```

and after just iterate through filepaths to print each file

Answer (score 0):

I got to print by looping on directory files. But this causes print process to run in authomatic mode, and one for every file to be printed. This is not what I need: i wish to simulate the multiselection and printing.
I tried to run the "print" command in the Windows command shell

```html
Dim pr As New System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog
                Dim myprinter = pr.PrintQueue.QueuePort.Name


Dim files = "C:\pic1.jpg C:\pic2.jpg"
Dim command = String.Format("/C print /D:{0} {1}", myprinter, files)
info.FileName = "cmd.exe"
info.Arguments = command
```

the command string generated is

/C print /D:HPColorLaserJetM553 C:\pic1.jpg C:\pic2.jpg

which doesnt work, even if the process ends without apparent errors.
If i try to run the command string from windows shell, I get the error

"could not initialize the device D:HPColorLaserJetM553"

Comment: maybe I should run something like this:
rundll32    shimgvw.dll    ImageView_PrintTo /pt   "C:\pic1.jpg" "HP Color LaserJet M553 PCL 6"

but, as above, it works only for ONE file, and print process starts in batch mode. how can I set up parameters so that it work for several pictures?

Answer (score 0):

Store all files path in a `string[]` or `char[][]` (Array of string)
then loop this instruction:

```cmd
rundll32 shimgvw.dll ImageView_PrintTo /pt "files[i]" "HP Color LaserJet M553 PCL 6"
```